# How to add Column fields from Parent class coming as an external Jar in Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have an Address class that looks like

```
@Entity
@Table("address)
public class Address extends com.sample.Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
}
```

This com.sample.Address has follwing fields :
eg :

```
street1
street2
zipcode
...
```

I want to include fields from com.sample.Address class in the DB table address with minimal code changes, so the output looks like :

```
Table address
id
street1
street2
zipcode
..
```

Note : This com.sample.Address doesn't have Entity.

Comment: Does it have `@MappedSuperclass` or `@Embeddable`? I believe either of those would be necessary. Otherwise you can try to override getter/setter and annotate those in you `Address` class

Comment: Non-entity (ie unmapped) classes only provide inheritance behavior to the entity subclasses. You have to mark it with MappedSuperclass/Embeddable as @XtremeBaumer suggests (or as an Entity) for properties within them to be picked up and persisted.